# Разное позиционирование картинки в зависимости от ориентации мобильного устройства

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

В общем нужно что бы при вертикальной ориентации картинка была так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при горизонтальной так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написать медиа запрос для горизонтальной ориентации, например:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 480px) {
    img {
        // your style
    {
}
```

Больше инфо: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)